# ActiveRecord insert return PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I already searched on SO and I find an answer about the error but my issue is little different. I have this error:

```
PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24/05/2016 17:00"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

If I look at the logs

```
    pry(#<WebexSync::Sync>)> attributes
    => {:webex_external_id=>1025, :user_id=>2565, :lesson_times=>[2016-05-24 17:00:00 +0200], :status=>"invited"}

pry(#<WebexSync::Sync>)> UserWebex.create! attributes
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2565]]
  Webex Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "webexes".* FROM "webexes" WHERE "webexes"."external_id" = $1  ORDER BY "webexes"."start_date" DESC LIMIT 1  [["external_id", 1025]]
  UserWebex Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "user_webexes" WHERE ("user_webexes"."user_id" = 2565 AND "user_webexes"."webex_external_id" = 1025) LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "user_webexes" ("webex_external_id", "user_id", "lesson_times", "status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["webex_external_id", 1025], ["user_id", 2565], ["lesson_times", "{24/05/2016 17:00}"], ["status", "invited"]]
PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24/05/2016 17:00"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
: INSERT INTO "user_webexes" ("webex_external_id", "user_id", "lesson_times", "status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24/05/2016 17:00"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

I cannot figure why my object params are ok, and the date is in this format `[2016-05-24 17:00:00 +0200]`, but while saving ActiveRecord change the format in `["lesson_times", "{24/05/2016 17:00}"]`

lesson_times is an array

Answer (score 1):

As the error says: `HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.`
, and it's quite true.

Here's how you can set a different `datestyle` in PG.

```
SET datestyle = "ISO, DMY";
```

Comment: May be the date you are trying to put is in wrong style/format. Try other formats.